# UTC offset not correct using tz_localize and ZoneInfo

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, zoneinfo

I have a `pd.DatetimeIndex` object in local time without UTC offsets. I am now trying to localize this object using `tz_localize` and a `ZoneInfo` object so that it contains UTC offset information, i.e. turn `'2023-10-29 02:00:00'` into `'2023-10-29 02:00:00+02:00'` for a specific timezone (e.g. 'Europe/Amsterdam').

For replication purposes, the below code builds the object that I am working with.

```
pd_local_no_tz = pd.date_range('2023-10-29', '2023-10-30', freq='H', tz=ZoneInfo('Europe/Amsterdam')).tz_localize(None)

Out[17]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2023-10-29 00:00:00', '2023-10-29 01:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 02:00:00', '2023-10-29 02:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 03:00:00', '2023-10-29 04:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 05:00:00', '2023-10-29 06:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 07:00:00', '2023-10-29 08:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 09:00:00', '2023-10-29 10:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 11:00:00', '2023-10-29 12:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 13:00:00', '2023-10-29 14:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 15:00:00', '2023-10-29 16:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 17:00:00', '2023-10-29 18:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 19:00:00', '2023-10-29 20:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 21:00:00', '2023-10-29 22:00:00',
               '2023-10-29 23:00:00', '2023-10-30 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

The original `pd.DatetimeIndex` object already contains the correct clock changes with '2023-10-29 02:00:00' appearing twice (without UTC offset).

I am now trying to localize the `DatetimeIndex` the following way using `ZoneInfo`:

```
pd_local = pd_local_no_tz.tz_localize(ZoneInfo('Europe/Amsterdam'), ambiguous='infer')
```

However, the resulting `pd.DatetimeIndex` now contains twice the entry `'2023-10-29 02:00:00+02:00'` although the second one should have a different UTC offset, namely `'2023-10-29 02:00:00+01:00'`:

```
Out[21]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2023-10-29 00:00:00+02:00', '2023-10-29 01:00:00+02:00',
               '2023-10-29 02:00:00+02:00', '2023-10-29 02:00:00+02:00',
               '2023-10-29 03:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 04:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 05:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 06:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 07:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 09:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 10:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 11:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 12:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 13:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 14:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 15:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 16:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 17:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 18:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 19:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 20:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 21:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 22:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 23:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-30 00:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq=None)
```

When doing the same thing without using `ZoneInfo`, the UTC offset is correct:

```
pd_local = pd_local_no_tz.tz_localize('Europe/Amsterdam', ambiguous='infer')

Out[23]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2023-10-29 00:00:00+02:00', '2023-10-29 01:00:00+02:00',
               '2023-10-29 02:00:00+02:00', '2023-10-29 02:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 03:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 04:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 05:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 06:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 07:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 09:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 10:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 11:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 12:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 13:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 14:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 15:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 16:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 17:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 18:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 19:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 20:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 21:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 22:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 23:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-30 00:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq=None)
```

How can I get the correct UTC offset when transforming the `DatetimeIndex` object using a `ZoneInfo` object?

I use Python 3.9 and pandas 1.5.3 and its important for me to use `ZoneInfo` because `pytz` does not handle clock changes past 2037. So the goal is to properly add UTC offset information to timestamps past 2037.

Comment: You do realize that time zones projected far into the future are almost guaranteed to be wrong?  You can't predict changes in the law.

Comment: I'm totally agree with @MarkRansom. In Europe, daylight saving time should be abandoned. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe#Future

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, I am aware that these can change over time, however I am interested in the current clock changes, and wondering whether it's an issue with `ZoneInfo` or whether I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that the issue has been fixed with pandas 2.0. It now returns the correct timezone offset.

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
pd_local_no_tz = pd.date_range('2023-10-29', '2023-10-30', freq='H', tz=ZoneInfo('Europe/Amsterdam')).tz_localize(None)
pd_local = pd_local_no_tz.tz_localize(ZoneInfo('Europe/Amsterdam'), ambiguous='infer')
pd_local
Out[6]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2023-10-29 00:00:00+02:00', '2023-10-29 01:00:00+02:00',
               '2023-10-29 02:00:00+02:00', '2023-10-29 02:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 03:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 04:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 05:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 06:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 07:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 09:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 10:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 11:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 12:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 13:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 14:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 15:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 16:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 17:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 18:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 19:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 20:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 21:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-29 22:00:00+01:00',
               '2023-10-29 23:00:00+01:00', '2023-10-30 00:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Amsterdam]', freq=None)
```